# Question on retrieving information on file in application directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a program which i can download a video file from a server to the app's directory but how do i retrieve the information about this file (mp4). I would like know the size of that file and it there a way to know when the file is being created as in a date or time? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *fileInfo = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: filePath error: &error];
if ( fileInfo ) {
    // examine fileInfo, see NSDictionary (NSFileAttributes) in NSFileManager.h
} else {
    // handle the error
}
```